# lua __index metamethod called with different table

Tags: lua

I'm trying to calculate top, bottom, right and left properties of a rectangle on fly, instead of keeping them in the table.

```
Rect = {}

Rect.__index = Rect

setmetatable(Rect, {
            __index = function(tbl,key)
                if key == 'right' then
                  return tbl.x + tbl.width
                elseif key == 'top' then
                  return tbl.y
                elseif key == 'left' then
                  return tbl.x
                elseif key == 'bottom' then
                  return tbl.y + tbl.height
                end

                return rawget(tbl,key)
               end
})

function Rect.new(x, y, width, height)
    return setmetatable( { x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height }, Rect )
end

function Rect:intersectsWith(other)
    return not (other.left > self.right or other.right < self.left or other.top > self.bottom or other.bottom < self.top)
end
```

What's confusing to me is:

If

```
Rect.__index = Rect
```

serves so instances can fall back to Rect for all missing methods, where would my custom __index implementation go ? I've tried to put it in the Rect metatable because _index methods can be chained.

The result is that __index gets called but with wrong table. It crashes because tbl.x and lua can't perform arithmetics with it. My guess is that the passed table is the Rect table itself since the calls are chained.

Comment: Determining if your guess is correct should be as simple as printing out the passed value and the `Rect` table (or testing them for equality directly). So you should be able to do that easily enough. That being said I believe you are correct.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Yep, Rect is passed, I've just checked. I thought the instance table would be passed?

Comment: An `__index` metamethod gets the table it is associated with passed to it. Consider that what has happened is that you've failed to find the key in your instance (`r` say), looked it up in the `__index` table, failed to find it there and then called the `__index` metamethod on the `__index` table (which is `Rect` in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua checks if a key is in the indexed table before calling its `__index` metamethod, so `return rawget(tbl,key)` is redundant.

What you really want is `return Rect[key]`, which will look for values in the `Rect` table like the `__index=tbl` shortcut does.

Comment: True, but remember that this is a Rect metatable, not the instance. Rect[key] for a missing value would cause a stack overflow because the same __index metamethod would be called.

Comment: The suggestion here is that you perform the chaining manually instead of by chaining `__index` tables. So attach that metatable to your instance and then use that return line to chain up. At least as I understand it.